# How to install CUDA on Linux Mint with Xen already installed?

Tags: nvidia, xen, cuda

Xen is installed on Linux mint. How to install CUDA without getting a black screen or command line on restart?

In other words, how to get Xen's Dom0 Mint Desktop with CUDA installed?

Answer (score 1):

Best lead so far is that it seems that NVIDIA does not work with Dom0 Xen but there might be a workaround that exists involving (re)building NVIDIA drivers with a 'IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=y' parameter :

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/NvidiaWithXen

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/691565/geforce-driver-problem-on-centos-6-4-with-xen-installed/

Comment: To the best of my understanding this issue seemed to be shared by many :

https://www.xenproject.org/questions-and-answers/how-can-i-use-cuda-on-dom0-with-nvidia-geforce-gt630.html | https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/823527/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-7-trouble-running-devicequery-and-all-other-samples/ | https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/824340/cuda-setup-and-installation/gtx-750-ti-blank-screen-on-xen-4/ | https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13121/gpgpu-cuda-in-kvm-or-xen?rq=1

Comment: Incidentally there seem to be options to switch between Nouveau and NVIDIA drivers 'on the fly' if it would help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16998/switch-between-nvidia-current-and-nouveau-without-a-reboot?rq=1 | https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nouveau_%26_nvidia-drivers_switching | https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nouveau | https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks#Switching_between_NVIDIA_and_nouveau_drivers